# what is the purpose of javax StreamSource

Tags: java, xml

I am parsing an xml document being read in as an InputStream, and an [example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html) I've seen first stages the stream in a javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource.  Why do this when I can parse the stream as it's read in?  The Java API's [description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) isn't helpful: "Acts as a holder for a transformation Source in the form of a stream of XML markup."

Example with StreamSource:

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource reportStream = 
              new StreamSource(new URL("file:///myXmlDocURL.xml").openStream());
    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(reportStream);
    xmlReader.nextTag();
    while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
        if (xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("attributeICareAbout")) {
            String tempTagValue = xmlReader.getText();
            xmlReader.nextTag();
        }
    }
    xmlReader.close();
```

Example without StreamSource:

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();        
    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = 
      xif.createXMLStreamReader(new URL("file:///myXmlDocURL.xml").openStream());
    xmlReader.nextTag();
    while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
        if (xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("attributeIcareAbout")) {
            String tempTagValue = xmlReader.getText();
            xmlReader.nextTag();
        }
    }
    xmlReader.close();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an abstraction so that the same parsing code can be used for a variety of sources (note:  `StreamSource` implements `Source`):

- [XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLStreamReader%28javax.xml.transform.Source%29)
- [Validator.validate(Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate%28javax.xml.transform.Source%29)
- [Transformer.transfrom(Source, Result)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29)
- [Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Source, Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29)

Getting XML from a file is just one possibility.  There are also implementations of `Source` for DOM (`DOMSource`), SAX (`SAXSource`), StAX (`StAXSource`), and JAXB (`JAXBSource`).